# how to pull data source information on data-driven subscriptions

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssrs

I would like to know more about the data-driven subscriptions on our ReportServer.  I am specifically looking for what shared data sources are being used, but the connection string would also suffice.

I have poked around the `Subscriptions` and `DataSource` tables, but nothing seems to give me the information I need.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I kept poking around and... found it.  For the future reference of others:

```
select 
  Catalog.Name
, Subscriptions.[Description]
from
  Subscriptions
  join DataSource
    on Subscriptions.SubscriptionID = DataSource.SubscriptionID
  join Catalog
    on DataSource.Link = Catalog.ItemID
```

Comment: Thanks for adding your own solution! Don't forget to accept it if it solved your case.